# return the grep result to a variable, do it in python?

Tags: python, bash, grep, subprocess

I would like to grep the pattern and return it to a variable, for multiple files, I know how to do it using bash, but now I want to realize it in python.

In bash, I can do something like this

```sh
for i in {1..3}
do
  result=$(grep "pattern" folder/name-${i}/out)
done
```

However, I'm not sure how to do it in Python.
I tried:

```
for i in range(1,4):
    name = 'name-' + str(i)
    result = subprocess.check_output("grep 'pattern' folder/{name}/out", shell=True)
```

It returns error `grep: folder/{name}/out: No such file or directory`

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: The error explains itself, `folder/{name}/out` is not a valid path

Comment: You missed an `f` before the string to make it an f-string.

Comment: The variable in your string is not resolved to the variable. You need to format the string. Also if you want to solve it "more" in Python: https://regex101.com/ There is a Python code generator on the website. Because you are still doing the regex work in sh.

Comment: Running `grep` from Python is almost always easy to avoid by doing the regex search in Python itself. Avoiding an external process is usually a performance win, and often, you can optimize the overall flow by doing things natively. In brief; `import re; with open(f'folder/{name}/out') as thing: result = [line for line in thing if re.match('pattern', line)]`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put an `f` before `"grep 'pattern' folder/{name}/out"`. So you can use:

```py
for i in range(1, 4):
    name = 'name-' + str(i)
    result = subprocess.check_output(f"grep 'pattern' folder/{name}/out", shell=True)
```

Or you can use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    name = 'name-' + str(i)
    result = subprocess.check_output("grep 'pattern' folder/{name}/out".format(name=name), shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1,4):
    name='name-'+str(i)
    result=subprocess.check_output("grep 'pattern' folder/%s/out" % name, shell=True)
```

or with f before your command:

```
result = subprocess.check_output(f"grep 'pattern' folder/{name}/out", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `f` before the string to make it a `f-string`:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    name = 'name-' + str(i)
    result = subprocess.check_output(f"grep 'pattern' folder/{name}/out", shell=True)
```

Or you could do `%` string formatting:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    name = 'name-' + str(i)
    result = subprocess.check_output(f"grep 'pattern' folder/%s/out" % name, shell=True)
```